# Non-consensual sex leading to statutory rape

Tags: united-states, rape

In Texas (U.S.) if person A who is a 12-year old male overpowers and has penetrative sex with person B who is a 30-year old female, is person B guilty of statutory rape? Assuming neither person was intoxicated and person B had clearly verbally stated to person A that they do not wish to engage in sexual activities with them.

Comment: Surely you mean "would A be guilty of statutory rape"?

Comment: No, it's worded correctly.  A would be guilty of rape, but they're asking if B would be guilty of statutory rape (sex with a minor).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If an adult is raped by a minor, is it statutory rape?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15018/if-an-adult-is-raped-by-a-minor-is-it-statutory-rape)